# Debian 9 Dummy Output after resume from suspend (snd_hda_intel codec)

Tags: audio, driver, codec, debian-stretch

I have an external monitor that I plug-in my Dell laptop after turn it on. The sound works before and after plug it in the Laptop, So the headphone works too, plugin it in and out too. The problem is when I resume Debian after suspend. The sound has gone, and some times when increasing and decreasing volume one of the three options appears in the screen: Headphone unplugged, HDMI output (or something like), or Dummy Output.

I will show now what happens when Dummy Output is displayed and some outputs of commands.

```
$ lspci | grep Audio
```

Output:

```
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)

$ lsmod | grep hda
```

Output:

```
snd_hda_ext_core 28672 1 snd_soc_skl

snd_hda_intel 36864 0
snd_hda_codec 135168 1 snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_core 90112 4 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_ext_core,snd_soc_skl
snd_hwdep 16384 1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm 110592 6 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_ext_core,snd_hda_core,snd_soc_skl,snd_soc_core
snd 86016 7 snd_compress,snd_hda_intel,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_codec,snd_timer,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm

$ sudo dmesg | grep snd
```

Output (when rebooting):

```
[ 13.341580] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
[ 13.461226] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: CORB reset timeout#1, CORBRP = 0
[ 13.462799] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: no codecs found!

$ sudo alsactl init
```

Output:

```
alsactl: init:1757: No soundcards found...
```

Complete Alsa Information script:

```
https://alsa-project.org/db/?f=ff03c7d8dac369fc1211822de963b337c132420c
```

---

So it looks like the sound card is there but alsa does not recognize it.

Many forums/sites recommend to blacklist snd_hda_codec_hdmi (that would be the case when the problem is with connecting/desconnecting HDMI for the external monitor), and also put a line:

```
options snd-hda-intel model=generic
```

in a file, e.g., `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base-blacklist.conf`.

But it didn't work.

Other sites suggest to disable and enable sound in BIOS. Didn't work.

Can anyone help me solve this forever issue?

Comment: Did you try reporting a bug? https://alsa-project.org/wiki/Bug_Tracking

Comment: No, I didn't. I talked to a couple of guys at freenode IRC, alsa channel, but without success.

Comment: I will mention here that, even if I couldn't solve this problem in Debian 9, I've installed Debian 10 (Buster) in the laptop and the audio works like a charm, no problems at all. All working good. So I recommend to all that are in this "unsolvable" problem like me, to give a try to Debian 10.